# image does not appeared

Tags: java, android

i tried to create a menu, but the image does not appeared, there is an error in every android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:alphabeticShortcut='s'
        android:title="@string/save_menu_noteedit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="@string/delete_menu_noteedit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

i'm trying to make my action bar the same as the image above, how can i solve the problem? currently my menu just have the Note name but not the images

Comment: Hey @Chase, could you please be a bit more specific on this? Is there any text shown or nothing appears on your activity?

Answer (score 0):

That error is why it will not show. If you click the error and press alt + enter it should do this for you automatically.

In your menu resource file add

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to the `menu` tag, and for each item use

```
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

This assumes that you are using an `AppCompatActivity` or any of its derivatives. If you are using regular activities it could just be because there isn't enough room to display the icon.

Comment: @chase What type of activity are you using? Standard/support/appcompat/etc and which application theme.

Comment: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">